# Lubuntu Uninstalled Icon remains

Tags: lubuntu, uninstall

I installed Skype and found it wasn't really working so I uninstalled it; but the icon is still on my desktop (I use the netbook remix). It's also still listed in the menu under internet. How do I get rid of it? Why didn't the uninstall also get rid of the icon?

Answer (score 0):

It should have.  An easy way to get rid of the desk top icon is to delete it, right click and choose move to trash.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be an option in lubuntu. The only right click option I have is "customize" which doesn't lead anywhere helpful.

Comment: Open PCManFM and navigate to Desktop.  Right click the desktop icon there and choose move it to trash.